# Select2 won't format items

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I don't know if it's conflicts with new libraries and such but I can't format the select items. They won't format to italic & bold.

http://jsfiddle.net/fcb960xh/2/

```
<select style="width: 300px">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone">
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone">
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').select2({
      // Specify format function for dropdown item
      formatResult: formatResult,
      // Specify format function for selected item
      formatSelection: formatSelection
    });
});

function formatResult(item) {
    if(!item.id) {
       return item.text;
    }
    // return item template
    return '<i style="color:#ff0000">' + item.text + '</i>';
}

function formatSelection(item) {
    // return selection template
    return '<b>' + item.text + '</b>';
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using select2 4.0.0. Things have changed from previous versions.

From [select2 4.0.0 announcements](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#changed-templating):

> Select2 previously provided multiple options for formatting the results list and selected options, commonly referred to as "formatters", using the formatSelection and formatResult options. As the "formatters" were also used for things such as localization, which has also changed, they have been renamed to templateSelection and templateResult and their signatures have changed as well.

You should use `templateResult` and `templateSelection` instead of `formatResult` and `formatSelection`. You should also return a jQuery object. Here's the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fcb960xh/7/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used select2 but a quick way could be just to add style to existing css class

```
.select2-results__group{
    font-style: italic
}
```

Take a look : https://jsfiddle.net/fcb960xh/9/